# How can I make Chrome work with OSS?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, audio, arch-linux, flash-player

I had to install OSS on my new Arch system because ALSA didn't work (I tried disabling snd_intel8x0m). Flash in Firefox produces sound, but Chrome's Flash doesn't work. libflashsupport-oss is installed.

I tried joining the HTML5 trial on YouTube, but videos don't even play when it's enabled, so I have to stick with Flash.

Comment: Note that HTML5 does not work for all videos.

Comment: My problem with HTML5 is that even videos that are supposed to work with it are just buffered and searchable (I can change frames manually), but they don't play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19470) in the Chromium repo, and it states that OSS is not supported and won't be. There are workarounds like [this](http://www.opensound.com/wiki/index.php/Tips_And_Tricks#ALSA_Emulation), but they produce unsynchronized audio.